# (Uncountable) Union of Sets Equivalent to Disjoint Union?

Tags: set-theory

There are some questions posted on the countable case ([Countable Union to Countable Disjoint Union](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/978519);  [Writing an Infinite Union as the Union of Disjoint Sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/322810); [union of sets disjoint sets is equal to the union set difference](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1024705)). I can't see why this wouldn't extend to the uncountable case, and **would appreciate correction or confirmation for my proof below**......

**Proposition:** if $\{B_α\}_{ α ∊ A }$ is any collection of sets and $B = \cup_{ α ∊ A} B_α$
 then there is a collection of pairwise disjoint sets $\{C_α\}_{ α ∊ A }$ with $B = \cup_{ α ∊ A} C_α$. Furthermore, for all $α,  C_α \subset B_α$ 
(So, this applies to uncountable, countably infinite, and finite collections).

**Proof:**
By the axiom of choice we can assume that $A$ is well-ordered with a minimum element $α_0$, and that every non-empty subset of $A$ has a minimum element (which is relevant in steps (2) and (3)).
Define $C_{α_0} = B_{α_0}$ and for $α > α_0$,  $C_α = B_α \setminus (\cup_{ β < α} B_β)$ .

1. Then for all $α,  C_α ⊂ B_α$.
2. Among sets {$C_α$} which contain some particular element $x$, let $γ$ be the smallest value of $α$. 
   Then $x ∊ C_γ ⇒ x ∊ B_γ$ and $x ∉ B_β$ for $β < γ$. So $x ∉ C_β$ for $β < γ$.
   And, $x ∊  \cup_{ β < α} B_β$ for $α \ge γ  ⇒ x ∉ C_α$ for $α > γ$.
   Therefore the sets {$C_α\}_ {α ∊ A}$  are pairwise disjoint.
3. Now for some particular element $x \in B = \cup_{ α ∊ A} B_α$, let $γ $ be the smallest value of $α$ such that $x \in B_γ$. 
   Then $x ∊ C_γ ⇒ x \in \cup_{ α ∊ A} C_α ⇒ B = \cup_{ α ∊ A} B_α \subset \cup_{ α ∊ A} C_α$.
   Conversely, for some particular element $x \in  \cup_{ α ∊ A} C_α$ , let $γ$ be the smallest value of $α$ such that $x ∊ C_γ$. 
   Then $x \in C_γ ⇒ x \in B_γ ⇒ \cup_{ α ∊ A} C_α \subset \cup_{ α ∊ A} B_α$.
   So, $B = \cup_{ α ∊ A} B_α = \cup_{ α ∊ A} C_α$.

Comment: Right on. Moreover, I think your Proposition is *equivalent* to the axiom of choice.

Comment: By "every subset of $A$ has a minimum element" you mean (of course) "every nonempty subset of $A$ has a minimum element." But you don't have to say that, that's what it means for $A$ to be well-ordered.

Comment: @bof Yes, non-empty. I haven't seen how to prove the reverse for equivalence - want to post it as an answer ?